# Installing ImageMagick/imagick on shared host

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Ok, I'm trying to install something for my website, which requires ImageMagick and imagick. It's driving me nuts because I'm a noob and not entirely sure what I'm doing. When I try and run configure on imagick, I get the following:

"checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program."

So when I try and find out what that means, it looks like I need libmagick9-dev, which I can't install myself on shared hosting, from what I can tell. apt-get won't work since I have to be root and, obviously, I can't sudo either. Is there any other way I can install this?

Also, if I try and install MagickWand, I get:

"Cannot locate configuration program MagickWand-config"

Comment: Can you ask the host to install it for you on the server?

Comment: I can, and did. They said no, as well as "Yes, that's correct. You don't need sudo to install software under your user account."
But does the same go for the library or whatever that I'm trying to install? I can't use aptitude because:
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13 Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Answer (score 2):

In general, on shared hosting environments, trying to install anything custom onto the system is a lost cause.

Some hosts will install things for you.

You can either ask the host and hope they do install it OR go with a different plan that lets you configure the entire system - that can be a hosted private (virtual) server or your own server that you route traffic to.

Perhaps a better approach would be to ask the question about what it is that you are actually trying to accomplish.  Maybe you don't need the thing you are trying to install that also requires ImageMagick and imagick.